# Adding to status inside resque-status job

Tags: ruby, resque, resque-status

I'm trying to pass a value from inside my job to the status hash, exactly as described here: https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status#passing-back-data-from-the-job

But I don't understand how I'm supposed to do it. Here's my job class:

```
module ResqueJobs
  class MyJob
    include Resque::Plugins::Status

    @queue = :jobs_queue

    def perform
      self.status['output_url'] = 'something'
    end

  end
end
```

But when I check the job after completion:

```
status = Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.get(job_id)

logger.debug('STATUS CHECK:')
logger.debug(status.to_s)
```

The 'output_url' key is never there.

Comment: facing the same issue. there is a github issue that describes a workaround, but it didn't work for me: https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status/issues/66

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
set_status(key: "value", another_key: "another_value")
```